# Reading result from linq select query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two list (A & B) both of the same custom type (shown below)

```
MyClass
{
    id as string
    acidity as double
    region as string
}
```

I need to loop through list A and see if the id is in list B. If it is in list B I need to copy the region from list B to list A. What is the best way to do this? A simple example below,

```
List A             List B
id   region        id      region
abc                njp     EU
mno                plm     US
jkl                mno     US
                   abc     EU
```

Result I'm looking for

```
List A
id    region
abc   EU
mno   US
jkl
```

I am thinking of looping through each id in list A and using a linq query like below. However I have two issues,

```
 var reg = from b in B
 where A[i].id == b.id
 select b.Region;
```

I know the linq query above will return one value or no values. So how do I get the result into my A[i].Region variable? Also how can I deal if there is no result returned? Do I have to use a foreach even though I know there is only result at max?

Comment: Are you actually trying to modify the objects within list A, or add new entries to list B? I'm having trouble understanding your question at the moment.

Comment: Apologies. I am trying to modify the objects with list A. I'll try to rephrase my post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, it sounds like you probably want a join so that you can identify pairs, then you can copy the regions:

```
var query = from itemA in listA
            join itemB in listB on itemA.id equals itemB.id
            select new { itemA, itemB };

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    pair.itemA.Region = pair.itemB.Region;
}
```

Comment: I get the an error message. Saying the name itemA & itemB doesn't exist in the current context in the foreach loop? Is there also a difference in using == against equals?

Comment: @mHelpMe: There was a typo in my answer before, but it should work now. You need to use `equals` rather than `==` for a join - that's just how joins in LINQ work.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code:

```
foreach(var a in listA)
{
    var bForA = listB.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == a.id);
    if (bForA != null)
        a.Region = bForA.Region;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without temprary list declaration
`(from a1 in a
  from b1 in b
  where a1.id == b1.id && a1.region != b1.region
  select new {selectedA = a1, selectedB = b1}).ToList().ForEach(x => x.selectedA.region = x.selectedB.region);`